# Editing .plist file of an app

Tags: iphone, ios, bash, shell, plist

I'm creating an sbsettings toggle for a cydia app with a on/off button in settings.

I've downloaded the "SBsettings Scripty" from insanely cydia repo which is a prebuilt toggle. I need to write the command to execute when the button is toggled on and off.

There are 2 files to edit:

1- com.mytoggle.toggle1-launch-when-toggle-is-on

It contains by default:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm /var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.mytoggle.toggle1.flagfile
echo "the toggle is now OFF" >>/var/mobile/scripty.txt
```

This turns the toggle off and writes "the toggle is now OFF" in `scripty.txt`.

The other file, com.mytoggle.toggle1-launch-when-toggle-is-off, does exactly the opposite: turns the toggle ON and writes "the toggle is now ON".

I'm trying to replace this script; instead of writing text in scripty.txt, I want to change values in the .plist of the app.

This is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>something1</key>
    <false/>
    <key>something2</key>
    <false/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to replace `</false>` of the `<key>something1</key>` with `</true>` which will turn the button on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a great tool in OS X for this, called PlistBuddy, so you don't have to do crazy sed or perl to update these values. (See [its manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) for more information.)

Sample usage, to toggle your key named "something1" true or false:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :something1 true" /path/to/your.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :something1 false" /path/to/your.plist
```

Thus, to solve your problem, just replace that echo that prints to "scripty.txt" with the appropriate PlistBuddy call to turn that key on or off.